# How to remove same adjacent line/lines in a file using python?

Tags: python, scripting

I have a file with same/duplicate adjacent lines (n number), is there way I can remove these duplicate adjacent lines form the file??

My file looks something like this:

```
Python is good  
python is good   
python is best  
python is best  
python is best  
Best scripting language  
Best scripting language  
Best scripting language
```

And I am looking for output like this:

```
Python is good  
python is best  
Best scripting language
```

Here is the code, where "sample_list" is a list that I have created in earlier portion of my script... and as I am using for loop my "newfile" is written with same (number of elements in the list "sample_list") adjacent lines .  So I am trying to eliminate the same adjacent lines

```py
file1  = open(filename, 'r')  
file2 = open('newfile', 'w')  
for line in file1:  
   for s in sample_list:  
       sample = line.replace('better', s )  
       file2.write(sample)  
file1.close()  
file2.close()
```

Comment: So where's your code, and what exactly is the problem with it? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: In a *nix shell: `uniq -i < f.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check whether the new `sample` differs from the previous one:

```
newSample = line.replace('better', s)
if newSample.lower() != oldSample.lower():
    file2.write(newSample)
oldSample = newSample
```

The conversion to lower case via `lower()` lets you ignore the case when comparing strings.

Note that I haven't tested these lines of code. You'd probably need to initialize `oldSample` before entering the for-loop.